# Memory usage going up.  Memory released is not being reused

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm using [debug_new](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm) to find memory leaks . I'm deleting my objects and debug_new doesn't show any trace of me leaking them.

I've read several threads on memory fragmentation. But I'm still confused. At this point I'm testing my framework and I'm doing a simple test. I create a new objects like so:

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)){
    artemis::Entity& e = world->createEntity();
    e.addComponent(new PositionComponent(posX,posY));
    e.addComponent(new MovementComponent(500,0));
    e.addComponent(new SpriteComponent(TextureManager::getInstance().getTexture("bullet.png")));
    e.addComponent(new ColliderComponent(10,10));
    e.refresh();
    e.setGroup("BULLET");
}
```

These "components" are managed in a manager called "EntityManager" which reuses the Entity objects but destroys the components when the Entity is send back to the "pool".
I've tested this, and only new entities are made if no available entity is in the pool.

As you can see by the code above. In this simple test the patterns are the same. Yet the allocator keeps using new memory instead of reusing any previously used memory. Creating a few thousands per space-bar hit( per 1/60 a frame) caused my memory to go into the 2 gig spectrum. The components aren't even that big. For example:

```
class ColliderComponent : public artemis::Component{

    public:
    int width,height,collidionsId;

    ColliderComponent(int width, int height){
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
};
```

Most components are simple "collections" of ints so far. They are pretty lightweight. It should most definitely reuse some of the previously allocated/released memory. But it just doesn't.

Maybe I'm missing something. Does anyone have a different idea of what might be going on? And are there any good( free ) memory profilers?
If it's not because of my components, the flaw must be somewhere else. I simply can not see it at this point and it's frustrating to say the least.

Edit:
It looks like I was overlooking a different part which caused a major leak. This was obviously a dumb fault by myself.

This was the culprit:
e.setGroup("BULLET");

"BULLET" is saved as a pointer ( I should redesign this ) and was overriding pointers to the existing strings at the index of the entity id. I have no idea why I overlooked this but my memory allocation is stable now!

I could have used smart pointers, but so far I've been learning a lot from this! I feel like I have achieved something =D

Comment: How are you gauging the memory used?

Comment: It might sound silly. But I'm just checking the taskmanager. But even then this simple application should not exceed over 1 gig. Not in it's current state.

Comment: This is one of the reasons it's not wise to use dumb pointers.

Comment: `Memory` and `ram` are very poorly selected tags for this question. The better ones would relate to the programming language and OS you're using, so you get the attention of people with some familiarity. It helps to select the proper tags, because you'll get an answer much faster (and in addition will waste fewer people's time in the process). It would be helpful if you'd edit them appropriately.

Comment: Well It's more of a excercise. I avoided smart pointers to understand memory management/ life cycles etc better.
@KenWhite

Any suggestions then? Cause I understand the difference. I just don't know which one is best suited.

Comment: @Sidar, I edited both the title and tags of your question. (Tag information shouldn't be in the subject line; the tagging system works really well to categorize questions, and people watching the `C++` tag will notice it rather quickly if it's in the tags.)

Comment: For `e.addComponent(new ColliderComponent(10,10))`, where is the corresponding destruction? Is `new` overloaded for all your components to take memory from the `EntityManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an overloaded `new` operator in `ColliderComponent`, which leads me to believe you are always allocating from the heap, and giving the memory to your `EntityManager`. This would definitely look like a leak, that disappears as soon as your `EntityManager` gets destructed.

**Edit:** I understand more about how your code works now. Components are not cached by your `EntityManager`, only the `Entity` is.

Comment: So then what do you suggest? Cause I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: @Sidar: How did you imagine the Entity objects would get reused in the `EntityManager`? Was there an interface to pull a component out from the pool?

Comment: @Sidar: Does `artemis::Component` have a virtual destructor?

Comment: It does. It's actually a pure virtual destructor. For Polymorphism. But it's pretty much empty. There is nothing really in Component other than to provide a base class with a pure virtual destructor.

Comment: Your remove components code looks a little confusing to me. Are you sure all the components of an entity get deleted by that code?

Comment: Ah!
This was the culprit:
e.setGroup("BULLET");

"BULLET" is saved as a pointer ( I should redesign this ) and was overriding previously created strings. I have no idea why I overlooked this but my memory allocation is stable now!

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using the task manager to assess the memory consumption - most memory managers do not immediately return freed memory to the operating system (that's a fairly expensive operation) but keep the memory available for use of the application itself. So your application's memory manager (which is part of the C++ runtime) will have marked the block you released as free and is able to reuse it later on when another request for memory comes in.

This has performance advantages as the runtime's memory manager doesn't constantly have to call out to the OS to release and then reacquire memory.

Comment: I understand that. However. It looks like memory is never reused. It was exceeding the 2gig mark and kept going. This shouldn't happen for this example. I've seen "heavier" programs not even go beyond the 500mb.